# Has anything changed with selenium web driver or Chrome over this weekend?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While the web code has not changed, my selenium automation tests are unable to find some xpaths today.  I am not sure if there was an update? Has anyone else noticed this? I have went back, inspected the elements (all links), and tried different xpaths, and nothing is working.

Comment: Chrome probably upgraded automatically. Therefore, post your Chrome, ChromeDriver and Selenium versions and any exceptions you are coming across.

Comment: I have put it as an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually because of an upgrade to Chrome. The ChromeDriver can only support certain versions.

I can see that actually, within the past few days, Chrome has updated to v33:

http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.fr/2014/02/stable-channel-update_20.html

So I'd suggest you download the latest ChromeDriver from here:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/